# Maximum power draw on Pi Pico 3.3V rail with USB power

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, pi-pico

The Pi Pico [datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf) recommends a maximum power draw on the 3V3 pin (pin 36) of 300mA. However, the RT6154B [datasheet](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6154A=RT6154B/DS6154AB-03.pdf) indicates that up to 3A can be drawn when Vin > 3.6V, which is the case when powering the Pico from the USB connector with a 5V/3A power supply. I am considering a design where I would draw around 1A on the 3V3 rail. Should I use yet another power converter or can I safely draw the 1A from pin 36 ?

Answer (score 4):

You can safely draw the suggested 300 mA.

I don't know what damage you will cause to the traces if you draw more.  To find out you will have to ask the board designers.